# Matrix fill zero rows with one

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an Adjacency matrix A:

```
    [1] [2] [3]
[1]  1   0   1
[2]  0   0   0
[3]  0   0   0
```

i want a new matrix B filled with one in all rows with only zero so B:

```
    [1] [2] [3]
[1]  0   0   0
[2]  1   1   1
[3]  1   1   1
```

how can i do that i R

Comment: You should specify the rule by which the matrix nees to change into the desired format.

Comment: Try `i1 <- rowSums(A == 0) == ncol(A); A[i1] <- 1; A[!i1] <- 0`

Answer (score 3):

Since an adjacency matrix is nonnegative, you can just test for zero `rowSums`:

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 
              0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)

B <- A * 0  # 0-matrix same dimensions as A
B[rowSums(A) == 0, ] <- 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`apply()` can be useful here. Try

```
t(apply(A, 1, function(x){ifelse(x != sum(x), 0, 1)}))
```

Comment: I like the x != sum(x) part!

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` shown returns a vector with one element per row of `A` having the value TRUE if that row is all zeroes and FALSE otherwise.   Assign that vector to  `A` using recycling so that each column of A is filled with it.  Such assignment will also have the effect of converting FALSE and TRUE to 0 and 1.  The expression is compact, seems relatively straightforward to understand and does not use any packages.

```
replace(A, TRUE, apply(A == 0, 1, all))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

This variation is even shorter but is slightly trickier:

```
replace(A, TRUE, apply(!A, 1, all))
```

### Note

The input `A` in reproducible form is:

```
A <- matrix(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
m <- matrix( c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 3, byrow = T )
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

m <- matrix(rep(ifelse(rowSums(m) == 0, 1, 0), dim(m)[1]), nrow =  dim(m)[1])
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```